# Applications of Young's convolution inequality

Tags: inequality, fourier-analysis, convolution, harmonic-analysis, young-inequality

Recall that the convolution of two functions is given by 
$$f*g(y)=\int f(x)g(y-x)dx.$$
The well known inequality known as Young's inequality, say that 
$$\|f*g\|_r\leq\|f\|_p\cdot\|g\|_q $$
provided $\frac 1p + \frac 1q = 1 + \frac 1r$ and $1\le p,q,r\le\infty$. Obvious implications is that

- $L^1$ is a Banach algebra
- $L^\infty$ is an $L^1$-module with respect to convolution

Do you have any deeper applications/examples?

Comment: Could I convince you to write $(f*g)(y)$ rather than just $f*g$ on the definition (but obviously not in the inequality)?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks!

Comment: You could make that $L^\infty$ an $L^r$, of course.

Comment: @t.b. Sure, thanks and yes - I just took the first examples that popped up in my head. ;)

Comment: Could I convince you to write $(f\star g)(y)$ instead of $f\star g(y)$? I have always disliked this notation, just as $f\circ g(x)$ instead of $(f\circ g)(x)$.

Comment: @wildildildlife Well, it is a matter of taste I agree, I am used to $f*g(x)$. (Could I convince you to write $*$ instead of $\star$?)

Answer (score 2):

The solution of many initial value problems for linear partial differential equations is of the form $K*u_0$, where $u_0$ is the initial value and $K$ is a kernel associated with the equation. Young's inequality gives estimates of the of the solution in $L^p$ spaces in terms of the size of the initial value.

Consider for instance the heat equation in $\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,\infty)$:
$$
u_t-\Delta u=0,\quad u(x,0)=u_0(x).
$$
The solution is $u(x,t)=K_t*u_0(x)$, where
$$
K_t(x)=(4\,\pi\,t)^{-\tfrac{n}{2}}\,e^{-\tfrac{|x|^2}{4t}}
$$
is the heat or Gauss kernel. It is in $L^P(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $p\ge1$, and
$$
\|K_t\|_p\le C_p\,t^{-\tfrac{n}{2}\bigl(1-\tfrac{1}{p}\bigr)}.
$$
Then, if $u_0\in L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1+r^{-1}$, the decay in time of the solution in the $L^r$ norm is
$$
\|u(\,\cdot\,,t)\|_r\le C_pt^{-\tfrac{n}{2}\bigl(1-\tfrac{1}{p}\bigr)}\|u_0\|_q.
$$